# While loop only loops once

Tags: java, while-loop

Why does the `Coins` while loop in the code below only loop once?

The program is supposed to allow the player to take the amount of coins that they want and then if they want more coins can go back. For some reason though once you go through the `Coins` loop and exit it once, regardless of whether or not you got any coins, it no longer works.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Coins
{
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        int user;
        int coins=1000;
        int player=0;
        boolean Coins=true;
        boolean whatGame=true;
        while(whatGame)
        {
            System.out.print("Press 1 to get more coins\n");
            Scanner myScan=new Scanner(System.in);
            user=myScan.nextInt();
            if(user==1)
            {
                while(Coins)
                {
                    if((coins>100)||(coins==100))
                    {
                        System.out.print('\u000C');
                        coins=coins-100;
                        player=player+100;
                        System.out.print("Only "+coins+" coins left.\n\n");
                        System.out.print("You now have "+player+" coins.\n\n");
                        System.out.println("Press 1 to get more coins\n\nPress 2 to play another game");
                        user=myScan.nextInt();
                        if(user==1)
                        {
                            System.out.print('\u000C');
                            Coins=true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            System.out.print('\u000C');
                            whatGame=true;
                            Coins=false;
                        }
                    }
                    else if((user==1)&&(coins<=0))
                    {
                        System.out.print('\u000C');
                        System.out.print("Sorry no coins left.\n");
                        whatGame=true;
                        Coins=false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't see anything glaringly obvious. Put a breakpoint each time you take `nextInt()` and ensure that the value returned by the scanner is what you expect it to be.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through with a debugger?

Comment: Why do you use this code twice : `user=myScan.nextInt();` ?

Comment: I can't see where `whatGame` becomes `false`... The main loop will run forever.

Comment: `coins > 100 || coins == 100` can (should) be `coins >= 100`, also `coins = coins-100` can be `coins -= 100` (but that's not related to your problem).

Comment: You'll learn more from determining the problem by yourself than from being given an answer.

Comment: `if (...) { ... } else if (...) { ... }` without any other code in a while loop is not good (unless your if-statement or while conditions have side effects, which they don't here) (and may or may not have something to do with your issue) - what happens when neither of those are true? The loop will just run forever, doing nothing but checking those values.

Comment: This was the portion of the game that wasn't working there are more parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, i don't understand your game... but you set `Coins=false` inside the loop, then it will never run again.

If you try something like:

```
    if(user==1)
    {
        Coins=true;          //new line here
        while(Coins) {
```

the while loop will start everytime is needed.

You should reconsider reestructuring your solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
user=myScan.nextInt(); // from this moment on user may no longer be 1
if(user==1)
{
    System.out.print('\u000C');
    Coins=true;
}
else // thus this branch is executed
{
    System.out.print('\u000C');
    whatGame=true;
    Coins=false; // setting Coins to false, not re-entering loop
}
```